# microsoftgraph create mailFolder (parentFolderId not doing what I expected)

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I was trying to add a mailFolder in my application but ran into an issue where it will only create folders in the root.  Even using the Graph Explorer to add a mailFolder produces the same result.  Here is an example.

POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders
{
  "displayName": "Test",
  "parentFolderId": "Inbox"
}

But it does not matter what I enter for parentFolderId it keeps creating the folder in the root of my mailbox.  I have tried copying and pasting my Inbox id as well, same result; tried Inbox, Drafts, SentItems as well to test.

My assumption would be the folder would get created under the parentFolderId value.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Graph docs are misleading here. They tell you to set `parentFolderId`, but that value isn't settable. You should instead POST to the `/childfolders` of the folder where you want to create the new folder.

So in your case, where you want to create the new folder as a subfolder of Inbox, do:

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailfolders/inbox/childfolders

{
  "displayName: "Test"
}
```

Comment: Perfect thanks!  Yes the Graph docs are definitely misleading.